# Spring to Spring boot conversion - tomcat is up but hitting endpoint gives 401 Error "This application has no explicit mapping for / error,

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on migrating the spring project into spring boot. While migrating, I am importing the existing applicationcontext.xml file in my main class to import the existing beans defined for spring project. I did not use any `@ComponentScan` annotation. After doing this, my tomcat is up but while hitting the endpoint for health check, it gives an error 401 Error "This application has no explicit mapping for / error.

I have created a main class in a different package than the package where my api end points exist.  trIied adding the `@componentScan` annotation with the package for component scan then it gives an error "expecting a single bean but found 2". I am feeling I am missing some configuration to make it work.

The spring configuration had `web.xml` file with servlets and servlet mapping but I removed it since web.xml is not required for spring boot application. So I am wondering if i need to address the servlet mapping in some way for spring boot so that the mapping will work as it was working in spring.
Any guidance will be highly appreciated. Below is my code snippet.

**Application.java:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
public class Application {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

**Web.xml:**

```xml
<web-app 
  xmlns: xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML Schema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3.0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>Servelt 3.0 Web Application </display-name>
<session-config>
   <cookie-config>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
       <secure>true</true>
   <cookie-config>
</session-config>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer<servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.api.AppResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.wadl.disablewadl</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>jerserysecure</servlet-name> ServletCOntainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.secureapi.AppSecureResourceConfig</param-value>
  </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/api/*<url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>jerseysecure</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/secureapi/*<url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**AppResourceConfig.java:**

```
public class AppResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppResourceConfig {}{
      super();
    property("jersery.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server");
    packages("com.api");
    register(GsonProvider.class);
    register(RequestContextFilter.class);
    register(NotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
    register(DefaultExceptionMapper.class);
    }
    
}
```

**AppSecureResourceConfig.java**

```java
public class AppSecureResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppSecureResourceConfig{}{
      super();
    property("jersery.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server");
    packages("com.secureapi");
    register(GsonProvider.class);
    register(RequestContextFilter.class);
    register(NotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
    register(DefaultExceptionMapper.class);
    }
    
}
```

Below is the url used for health check:
localhost:8080/rest-api-web/api/health

Comment: The component-scan should be in the `applicationContext.xml` if you are migrating from Spring to Spring Boot I would expect 2 xml files needing to be loaded. One general (the `applicationContext.xml` and another servlet specific `<servletname>-context.xml`. Check your `web.xml` (assuming you have that) for which ones are loaded. I would also suggest to follow the best practices and place your `Application` class in a top-level package this will prevent issues in the future.

Comment: To better help you you might want to add your original `web.xml` so we can help to decide what to include in your configuration.

Comment: Please add the full `web.xml` not just some random snippets.

Comment: Added full web.xml in the description above.

Comment: Also added few more information for more code visibility

Comment: @M.Deinum Let me know if this information is not enough to understand the problem

Comment: You are using Jersey... Which would require additional configuration (or use the autoconfiguration) for Spring Boot.

Comment: I have added all the required dependencies for jersey in pom.xml. I think only thing required is convert web.xml to spring boot format.

Comment: No it isn't, I suggest a read of the Spring Boot documentation regarding Jersey and what to add.

Comment: This issue is resolved now. I have posted my solution in the below answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue with the below steps:

1. Removed all the jersey dependencies from pom.xml file and added spring boot starter dependency as below.

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2. In my Application.java class, I added a bean with annotation @bean for the servlet.

Application.java:

```
@Bean    
public ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> dispatcherApiServlet() {
  ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> servRegBean = new 
  ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet>();
  servRegBean.setServlet(new ServletContainer());
  servRegBean.addUrlMappings("/api/*");                       
  servRegBean.addInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application",
  "com.api.AppResourceConfig ");            
  servRegBean.addInitParameter("jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl",
  "true");
  servRegBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);        
  return servRegBean;
}
```

3. Optional: you can mark the config class with @configuration annotation but this is not mandatory